# How to mock backend response for http call in constructor

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to test a method that makes an http call and is also called in the constructor of my class

My class is:

```
export class Service {
    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData(): void {
        // Make http call
    }
}
```

My test is:

```
let service;
let mockBackend;

beforeEach(inject([BopUserService, MockBackend], (_service, _backend) => {
    service = _service;
    mockBackend = _backend;
}));

it('should load data', () => {
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: response})));
    });

    service.loadData();

    // Assert data has been loaded
});
```

I get an error saying the observable from the http call is undefined. How can I mock the response for both the http call in the constructor and http call in my test?

Comment: I wouldn't do the http call in the constructor in the first place. Load the data lazily, the first time (or each tme) it's needed. Mocking the service will then be much easier.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm gonna go with your suggestion, thanks.